# GET and POST a list with 1 million json objects in python

Tags: python, json, api, pagination

I am making a GET call to an API EP which will return me a list of json objects. The total count of json objects is 1 million. The header will indicate this count. I will be making multiple API calls to get the million json objects. I need to POST this 1 million json objects back to a different EP. What is a good way of implementing this ?
Do I need to fetch all response first and then POST them ? Will this not mean holding a list with 1 million json object in Memory ? or can I POST while I am getting back the GET response parallelly ?

Comment: You could use multiple threads. One thread calls the first API, then pushes the response into a queue, the other thread reads from the queue and posts it to the second API. This will allow them to run in paralllel, and you'll only need the memory for the batches that are in transit.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. Could you please point me to an example ?

Comment: @Barmar recommendation is sound though you can also start with reading and writing batches without threading and see how it goes. Since large API hits are susceptible to failures I might look at persisting the results to a local file that might be used to restart in a sane spot.

Comment: @JonSG lets say this is a microservice and if it dies for some reason then we will lose the local file after restart right ?

Comment: Likely but if this was a AWS lambda you could write the temp file to S3 and that might allow you to recover partway through a paged request to fetch from some other endpoint. My larger perspective is that the remote endpoint might be much less stable than your well written lambda and it would be great to be able to recover from a 500 error without restarting from scratch.